# mac+hadoop2.7.2+eclipse,I've been setting up the right environment hadoop,but the project when i "import org.apache.hadoop.io..." it was wrong

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

mac+hadoop2.7.2+eclipse,I've been setting up the right environment hadoop,but when i "import org.apache.hadoop.io..." it was show error,like there lack jar.

[image]

Please help, thanks!

Comment: You need to describe a bit more in detail what you tried and what does not work, the way the question is written currently, nobody will be able to help you...

Comment: sorry,my hadoop has right run ,but i use "eclipse" create a "java project",and write a java class named "WordCount", when write the namespace, "import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;" it shows wrong ,the wrong tips "the import org.apache can't be resolved", i don't know how to solve the problem, because i have define "Hadoop Map/Reduce" -- Hadoop installation directory  -- "/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec",thanks